# QGIS: how to identify a visible raster layer among large view (composition of rasters)?

Tags: qgis, raster, gui

I have QGIS project loaded with many raster files.

For a given area, (ex: under my mouse pointer), I am looking for way to identify which (raster)layer provides the visible data.

To start, I will already be happy with a simple solution using the GUI.

*I am working with QGIS 2.4 on Ubuntu*

Answer (score 1):

To start with, make a tileindex shapefile of your images with the gdaltindex utility. Edit the shapefile by adding new columns for your metadata like to which layer each image belongs to. Add the shapefile into your project and query it with the identify tool for finding the image metadata.

Comment: I got the idea. I managed to generated the shapefile with 26 elements, but I don't how to you add metadata and make the query.

Comment: In addition to check the process is there a "manual" possibility to click and get the name of all layers under a point or a shape ?

Comment: Tileindex is just a shapefile. Open it with QGIS for editing and add columns you want and update the values as you wish.

Comment: I get to this point, however the tileindex shapefile appears as a monobloc shape. I am just beginning with qgis, I guess I ignoring a basic query tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify a raster by clicking the icon *Identifier* (i<- icon) and clicking on the somewhere on a layer in the working area.

A (docked) panel *Identifying results* should appear with a list of elements placed under the pointer.

However, the function highlight does not work, and for layer in contrary to shapes, there is no contextual menu to select the layer directly (which is a problem when imported layer get the same names).